# Android Wear WatchFace 0 device compatible

Tags: android, android-manifest, wear-os

I'm trying to publish my watchface on Google Play, but when I Sign Apk only for Wear, and I upload it to Google Developer Console, I get 0 devices supported. My manifest has been built with Android Developers guides so it should be ok.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.type.watch" />

<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.permission.PROVIDE_BACKGROUND" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/playicon"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault" >
     <service
        android:name=".DigitalClockService"
         android:label="@string/app_name"
         android:allowEmbedded="true"
         android:taskAffinity=""
         android:permission="android.permission.BIND_WALLPAPER" >
         <meta-data
             android:name="android.service.wallpaper"
             android:resource="@xml/watch_face" />
         <meta-data
             android:name="com.google.android.wearable.watchface.preview"
             android:resource="@drawable/playicon" />
         <meta-data
             android:name="com.google.android.wearable.watchface.preview_circular"
             android:resource="@drawable/playicon" />
         <intent-filter>
             <action android:name="android.service.wallpaper.WallpaperService" />
             <category
                 android:name=
                     "com.google.android.wearable.watchface.category.WATCH_FACE" />
         </intent-filter>
    </service>
</application>
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot publish a wear apk as it. You have to embed it in a regular apk using the way described in [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/apps/creating.html#CreateProject)
It means that you will have two modules and that your final apk will have the wear apk embedded in the /res/raw/ folder.